# How to send notification with onesignal using a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, onesignal

```
function sendMessage(){
  $content = array(
      "en" => 'Testing Message'
      );

  $fields = array(
      'app_id' => "XXXXXXXXX",
      'include_player_ids' => $usertomemberonesignalid,
      'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
      'large_icon' =>"ic_launcher_round.png",
      'contents' => $content
  );

  $fields = json_encode($fields);
```

The problem is that it's currently working when typing player ids value inside `include_player_ids`  but I want to do it dynamically with a PHP variable.

Comment: `function sendMessage($user_to_member_onesignal_id){ ... 'include_player_ids' => $user_to_member_onesignal_id, ... }` Then call it with `sendMessage($variable)`

Comment: did exactly the same and still not working i even tryed with a string instead of $variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code from one of my existing project.

```
// pass your single or multiple device ids here to send notification

// for single
$device_ids = array($PLAYERIDFROMDB);

// for multiple from array
/*$device_ids = array(
'2c5d007-5985-4ad9-a1d7-f4ec7eb84f00', // device id 1 (register_id from onceSignal)
'2c5d007-5985-4ad9-a1d7-f4ec7eb84f00'  // device id 1 (register_id from onceSignal)
); */
$content = array(
    "en" => 'Notification Title'
);
$data = array(
        "image"          => 'your_image_url', 
        "title"          => 'your Title',
        "message"        => 'your Message'
    );
$fields = array(
    'app_id' => 'ONESIGNAL_API_KEY', // your api key
    'include_player_ids' => $device_ids,
    'data' => $data,
    'contents' => $content
);

$sendContent = json_encode($fields);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
                    array('Content-Type: application/json; 
                            charset=utf-8',
                            'Authorization: Basic ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY' // your api key
                    ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sendContent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: and how do i define playerID inside $device_ids array?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your support, your code it's working but, instead of string i want to add a variable so i could get user's player id from database, so: instead of $device_ids = array(
'2c5d007-5985-4ad9-a1d7-f4ec7eb84f00', // device id 1 (register_id from onceSignal)
'2c5d007-5985-4ad9-a1d7-f4ec7eb84f00'  // device id 1 (register_id from onceSignal)
);  i would like something like this: $device_ids = array(
'$PLAYERIDFROMDB', // device id 1 (register_id from onceSignal)
'$PLAYERIDFROMDB'  // device id 1 (register_id from onceSignal)
);  Do you think it's possible?

Comment: I tried adding variables but it just don't get executed

Comment: @HéctorC let me know which framework you are using i will update my answer as per the framework to show you how to do that using database.

Comment: not using php framework, player ID is stored in a variable

Comment: @HéctorC check updated answer i have commented array one and added your variable into ids try and accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: i get your point, but saldy it aint working, if i add a variable $playerID = 'someString' it works but, if i create a variable $playerID = $idFromDB it doesn't work, it only works when there's a string of playerid

Comment: @HéctorC you are having issue with your db i am sure you are not getting id from your db properly.

Comment: I fixed it, all i had to do is add global $myonesignalid  inside function, thank you for your support Ashfaq!